# problems on request POST mutation on GraphQL and REACT

Tags: reactjs, graphql, client, apollo-client, react-fullstack

i receive 400 bad request when i try to add a task on my website! need help =(
i see people also returning all the page `return()` in every function, should i do the same? or i can leave the return at the end of the code

```
import './App.css';
import Task from './Task';
import React from 'react';
import TaskForm from './TaskForm';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {useQuery,gql,useMutation} from '@apollo/client'

const GET_TASKS = gql`
  query GetTasks {
    tasks {
      name
      done
    }
  }
`;

const ADD_TASK = gql`
mutation newTask($input: taskInput!) {
  newTask(input: $input) {
    name
  }
}
`;

function App() {
  const taskss  = useQuery(GET_TASKS);
  console.log(taskss)
  
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(() => {
    const storedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    return storedTasks ?? [];
    //return storedTasks !== null ? storedTasks : [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }, [tasks]);


  const [addTaskMutation, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(ADD_TASK, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      setTasks(prevTasks => [...prevTasks, data.addTask]);
    }
  });

  function AddTask(name) {
    addTaskMutation({ variables: {input: name } });
  }


  function removeTask(indexToRemove) {
}
  
  function updateTaskDone(taskIndex, newDone) {
  }
  
  function getMessage() {
    const percentage = numberTotal === 0 ? 0 : (numberComplete / numberTotal) * 100;
    if (percentage === 0) {
      return 'no tasks complete ';
    }
    if (percentage === 100) {
      return 'nice job! ';
    }
    return 'keep it up! ';
  }

  function renameTasks(index, newName) {
  }

  const numberComplete = tasks.filter(t => t.done).length;
  const numberTotal = tasks.length;
    
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>{numberComplete}/{numberTotal} Complete</h1>
      <h2>{getMessage()}</h2>
      <TaskForm onAdd={AddTask} />
      {taskss.data && taskss.data.tasks && taskss.data.tasks.map((task, index) => (
        <Task
          {...task}
          key={index}
          onRename={newName => renameTasks(index, newName)}
          onTrash={() => removeTask(index)}
          onToggle={done => updateTaskDone(index, done)}
        />
      ))}
    </main>
  );

}

export default App;
```

i am showing you also the Schema

```
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('@graphql-tools/schema');
const { resolvers } = require('./resolvers');

const typeDefs = `#graphql

    type Query {
        tasks: [Task!]!
    } 

    type Mutation{
        newTask( input: taskInput!): Task
        updatedTask( id: ID!): Boolean
        deletedTask( id: ID!): Boolean
        updatedTitle( id: ID! input: titleInput!): Boolean
    }

    input titleInput{
        name: String!
    }

    input taskInput{
        name: String!
    }

    type Task {
        name: String!
        done: Boolean!
        id: ID!
    }
`
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
module.exports = {schema}
```

and this is the resolver, everything seems to work on apollo

```
const { client } = require('./controllers/tasks');

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    tasks: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const result = await client.search({
        index: 'tasks',
        body: {
          query: {
            match_all: {}
          }
        }
      })
      const tasks = result.hits.hits.map((hit) => {
        const task = hit._source;
        task.id = hit._id; 
        return task;
      });
  
      return tasks;
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    
    updatedTitle: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const { id ,input } = args;
      const newName = input.name
      const response = await client.update({
        index: 'tasks',
        id: id,
        body: {
          doc: {
            name: newName
          }
        }
      });
    },

    deletedTask: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const id = args.id
      await client.delete({
        index: 'tasks',
        id: id,
      });
    },


    updatedTask: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const id = args.id
      const task = await client.get({
        index: 'tasks',
        id: id
      });
      await client.update({
          index: 'tasks',
          id: id,
          body: {
            doc: {
              done: !task._source.done
            }
          }
        });
    },

    newTask: async (parent, {input}, context, info) => {  
      const newTask = {
        name: input.name,
        done: false
      };

      const result = await client.index({             
        index: 'tasks',
        body: newTask
      });

      const { _id } = result;                               
      newTask._id = _id;

      return newTask;
    }
  }
};

module.exports = { resolvers };
```

Comment: Post code of `TaskForm` also. Also ensure you check the response body of the 400 request to see what the actual error is. Open browser dev tools, find the 400, click on it and view the "preview" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your mutation in the client:

```
const ADD_TASK = gql`
mutation AddTask($name: String!) {
  addTask(name: $name, done: false) {
    name
    done
  }
}
`;
```

Now compare that to the mutations you have defined on the server:

```
type Mutation{
  newTask( input: taskInput!): Task
  updatedTask( id: ID!): Boolean
  deletedTask( id: ID!): Boolean
  updatedTitle( id: ID! input: titleInput!): Boolean
}
```

1. There is no `addTask` mutation
2. The `newTask` mutation takes a single parameter `input` of type `taskInput` - you are sending two parameters to `addTask`, `(name: $name, done: false)` - even if you fixed the name you'd still have a mismatch with the parameters

Comment: thank you for your reply !
i tried to fix the mismatch as you said, i updated the code can you check it?
someone also said that my schema does not have args.input.. so how do i pas the input?

Comment: Right now `name` has no way of getting to the `addTask` function but that's a different question.